# How to change the running python version?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I tried `pip install baselines` in the terminal but output the `imageio requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.17.`
However I changed my python version in .bashrc file. And I checked it using the following command. But the problem still remained. Is there a way to handle it? Thanks in advance!

```
python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Comment: Try `pip3 install baselines`, or `which pip`.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install baselines`, to force `pip` to use the Python version on your PATH.